# Windows Service cannot connect to SQL Server Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, sql-server-2019

I am thinking of moving from SQL Express Edition to Standard Edition.  So I am testing SQL Server Developer Edition to see if it gives us the anticipated performance gains.

But I cannot get a Windows service to connect to my instance of Developer Edition.
It connects fine to SQL Express.  It connects to the Developer Edition from a Web Service - Its just from the Windows service that it fails.

I have tried both Windows User connection with trusted_connection = true, and SQL Server Database User with UserId and Password: Both fail with the same error. (Login Failed for User)

If I run the same connection code in a console app from visual studio, with the same connection string - then it works OK

My service is developed in C# dotnetcore 3.1 - using basic ado.net SqlConnection/SqlCommand

The error is  Login failed for user 'MyUser'

The stacktrace is:

```
    Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

SQL Server Developer Edition (2019) is supposed to be full-featured, - but maybe there are some hidden restrictions?

I seen this similar SO Question [C# Windows service SQL Server connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355857/c-sharp-windows-service-sql-server-connection-issue) and the solution does not work in my case.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. It should have additional details as to the specific cause of the login failure.

Comment: The logs reveal "Login failed for user 'MyUser'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]"  But I changed the password - using copy/paste from the connection string to verify the old password.  And the new password gives the same errors. I can login via SSMS using the password . I got the service to print the connection string to the event log, and the password is correct

Comment: Does the password have quotes? I would expect your console app version with the same connection string to to have the same issue, though. What error do you see in the logs with Windows auth?

Comment: Thanks for the help: I have got it working for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM - the default Service Windows user.  Which leads me to believe its something to do with the special user that I created to run the service. - This is good enough for my purposes now, although I'm not happy running in the SYSTEM account, its better than not running at all

Comment: If the special user for the Windows service is a Windows domain account, it ought to be fairly straightforward. The account needs a login, database user, and appropriate db permissions. A failed login for a Windows account will also have more info in the SQL error log.

Comment: Given the pools of (SQL/Windows) Logins and Database Users aren't shared between SQL Server instances it sounds like they might be configured differently between Express and Developer. Things to check include: 1) Do the logins have the Roles that you expect? Do the logins have the "default database" setting that you expect (this catches out a lot of people)? Do the logins map to the database users that you expect? Do the database users have the permissions that you expect?